# How do I update golang from command prompt on Windows?

Tags: windows, go

I have 1.7 version of golang and I want to update golang to 1.8 from command prompt. Uninstalling and Installing it again is always an option, but can I update it using commands on Windows 8.1?

Comment: You should follow the [installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install), which include upgrade instructions (by way of removal and installation). It's done entirely from the command line (at least for Unix-based OSes).

Comment: What is your OS ?   Install is OS specific

Comment: I have windows 8.1

Comment: I gave up and did the manual way. Just delete the Go file in whatever location you placed it in (mine was in C drive), uninstalled the previous msi version (I think this step should be optional) and installed the latest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that GVM could be a good option for that. GVM is an interface to manage Go versions in your computer. It allows you to change the Go version and even installing/uninstalling different golang versions by command prompt.

You can install a new version by typing:

```
gvm install go1.4 -B
gvm use go1.4
export GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$GOROOT
gvm install go1.5
```

Or even get a list of golang versions installed in your computer:

```
gvm list
```

More information can be found on their website: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

Comment: In my personal experience gvm is not worth it. I've already had go set-up. I just wanted make the updating **easier/faster**. A couple of basic functionalities were not working. Doing it the regular way seems cleaner and better _(to me)_.

Comment: @Joyston. As far as I know it doesn't work on Windows(there is nothing about it on their website and I'm not a Windows user to be sure). However, it might work on the new bash for Windows 10. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 31):

Go can also be updated using the [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/golang) package manager. Run from an elevated shell to minimize the risk of installation issues.

Install using:

```
choco install golang -y
```

Update using:

```
choco upgrade golang -y
```

Comment: worked like charm updating from go1.11 to go1.16

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks @David :)

Comment: Even if the first installation was from an installer?

Answer (score 5):

The "normal" way for Windows is to use the MSI package that can be found here : https://golang.org/dl/.

Now if you *really* want to do it from the command line, you **will nee**d to know the version (current is 1.13.4). There are several ways I can think of, including scraping the golang website or leveraging the Docker tags matching image with *latest*.
If you're doing this for administrative reasons, the version can also easily just be an input variable in your system.

Once you know the version you need to download the file at `https://dl.google.com/go/go<version>.windows-amd64.msi`.
You can use something like wget for Windows or just Powershell capabilities :
`Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile go1.13.4.windows-amd64.msi https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.4.windows-amd64.msi`

Then you can just use the MSI in quiet mode :
`msiexec.exe /package go1.13.4.windows-amd64.msi /quiet`

Answer (score 1):

If using Chocolatey mode of upgrade as David suggested, there is a possibility that the GOPATH defined on your system may not match with the existing one (if you had set a custom path via manual install).
Chocolatey, will install the Go binaries under %USERPROFILE%/go/bin --> C:\Program Files\Go\bin
So please ensure the path and update your environment variables accordingly.

Installation message may look something like below, if the path changes.

"*Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
The upgrade of golang was successful.
Software installed as 'msi', install location is likely default.*"

Answer (score 0):

Update the go version in your project's `go.mod` and let the build tool handle the rest.

Maybe this is a recent feature? Its what I just did and worked flawlessly:

- set go 1.22.0 to get the `NewServeMux`,
- then `go run .`

go automatically downloaded the specified version and then ran

Answer (score -12):

A simple way is to use the update-golang script:

```
git clone https://github.com/udhos/update-golang
cd update-golang
sudo ./update-golang.sh
```

Comment: This is poor form, telling people to make a blanket download of your utility and then invoking it via sudo.   I looked at the repo and it looks relatively legit still poor form and should not be recommended.

Comment: Works for me, obrigada Everton/udhos :-)

Comment: Looks like it kind of worked for me :) had to simlink old /usr/bin/go which was still 1.6 to the newly installed /usr/local/go/bin/go afterwards.

Comment: sudo? sh? On windows?

Comment: this comment should really be removed since OP is asking for Windows.